# How is address recognized between wallets

Tags: wallet, address, public-key, pgp

Lets assume I create a wallet in Jaxx and Bittrex for ETH token which in turn creates public & private key pair. I am able to transfer coins between different wallets.

How is the address generated by Jaxx recognized by Bittrex wallet ? Is it because the underlying process of (PGP) generation of public key is same ?

How different is this process from PGP ?

Answer (score 1):

Addresses are a standard encoding of data used by Bitcoin and other altcoins. When you enter an address into a wallet, it will decode it in the specific way that all wallets know to decode an address.

> How different is this process from PGP ?

PGP has nothing to do with Bitcoin (or cryptocurrencies) at all whatsoever.

Comment: Will all the wallets use the same decoding schema for a coin like for example ETH. How would a wallet know. Are there any chances of collision ?

Comment: Presumably yes, they use the same encoding. A wallet would not know whether the same encoding is used; they just assume that it is and decode things as such. If it is not the same encoding, then the decoding will likely fail.